# How do I find the arctan of a complex number?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to simplify
$$\tan^{-1}\left(e^{ix}\right), x\in\mathbb{R}$$

$$=\\tan^{-1}\left(\cos x+i\sin x\right)$$

Using $$\tan^{-1}\left(a+b\right)=\frac12\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2a}{1-a^2+b^2}\right)+\frac12\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2b}{1+a^2-b^2}\right)$$

Gives $$\frac12\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2\cos x}{1-\cos^2x-\sin^2x}\right)+\frac12\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2\sin x}{1+\cos^2x+\sin^2x}\right)$$

$$\frac12\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2\cos x}{0}\right)+\frac12\tan^{-1}\left(\sin x\right)$$

Which is undefined (?), however if I enter the expression into my HP Prime with a value of x, say 0.23 it gives 0.785+0.116i

So which of these is correct, thanks for the help.

Comment: Note you have "$1-a^2+b^2$" on the third line but "$1-\cos^2x - \sin^2x$" on the fourth ("$-$" instead of "$+$")

Comment: @MPW That's actually correct since it's $(i \sin^2 x)$, but the $i$ got dropped in the second term which is a mistake.

Comment: @ConMan : My bad, didn't read what OP was actually doing. Lazy :(

Comment: [This might help.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Extension_to_the_complex_plane)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem with your derivation is that the identity only holds true *if* the respective terms exist (and also you dropped an $i$ in the second $\tan^{-1}$ term).

Instead, we can turn to the complex definition of the trigonometric functions:

$$\begin{eqnarray} \cos z & = & \frac{e^{iz} + e^{-iz}}{2} \\
\sin z & = & \frac{e^{iz} - e^{-iz}}{2} \\
\tan z & = & -i \frac{e^{iz} - e^{-iz}}{e^{iz} + e^{-iz}} \end{eqnarray}$$

If we set $w = \tan z$ then we can solve for $z$:

$$\begin{eqnarray} w & = & -i \frac{e^{iz} - e^{-iz}}{e^{iz} + e^{-iz}} \\
(e^{iz} + e^{-iz}) w & = & -i(e^{iz} - e^{-iz}) \\
(w + i) e^{iz} & = & (i - w) e^{-iz}\\
e^{2iz} & = & \frac{i - w}{i + w} \\
z & = & \frac{1}{2i} \log \frac{i - w}{i + w}
\end{eqnarray}$$

We have to be careful here, since the complex logarithm is a multi-valued function, but it is possible to find the desired values through a bit of algebra (which I will leave as an exercise).

Comment: Perhaps a bit more accurate to say that both the arctangent and logarithm are multi-valued functions, so when you choose particular branches to use for each, the formula may need to be adjusted to provide the correct coversion between those branches.

Comment: That's true. Since the period of the logarithm is $2 \pi i$ and tangent is $\pi$, they should line up just right but it's good to double-check those kinds of things.

Answer (score 5):

The real way to do this is to write
$$ w=\tan^{-1}z$$
$$z = \tan w = \frac{\sin w}{\cos w}=\frac{(e^{iw}-e^{-iw})/2i}{(e^{iw}+e^{-iw})/2} = \frac1i\frac{e^{2iw} - 1}{e^{2iw}+1}$$
$$iz(e^{2iw}+1) = e^{2iw} - 1$$
$$e^{2iw}(1-iz)= 1 + iz$$
$$e^{2iw}=\frac{1+iz}{1-iz}$$
Now you can solve for $w$ (i.e., $\tan^{-1}z$) by taking logarithms and dividing by $2i$.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that the purported identity doesn't even work over $\mathbb{R}$, see https://www.desmos.com/calculator/z2b80oe4ct

If you set $z=\arctan(e^{ix})$, you have
$$
e^{ix}=\tan z=\frac{\sin z}{\cos z}=\frac{1}{i}\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}
$$
and therefore
$$
ie^{ix}=\frac{e^{2iz}-1}{e^{2iz}+1}
$$
from which
$$
e^{2iz}=\frac{1+ie^{ix}}{1-ie^{ix}}
$$
The right-hand side simplifies nicely to
$$
i\frac{\cos x}{1+\sin x}
$$
so you know that the real part of $e^{2iz}$ is $0$. Writing $z=a+bi$ we have
$$
e^{2iz}=e^{-2b}e^{2ia}=e^{-2b}(\cos2a+i\sin2a)
$$
Thus $\cos2a=0$ meaning that $\sin2a=\pm1$.

If $\cos x>0$, we must have $\sin2a=1$ and
$$
2b=\log\frac{1+\sin x}{\cos x}
$$
If $\cos x<0$, we must have $\sin2a=-1$ and
$$
2b=\log\frac{1+\sin x}{-\cos x}
$$
Real logarithm in either case.

It remains to deal with the cases $x=\pm\pi/2$ where the expression $\cos x/(1+\sin x)$ isn't defined or is zero, but here $e^{ix}=\pm i$ and the arctangent isn't defined.

Comment: Thank you egreg for that interesting contribution.